# how to set always-use-default-target in spring security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I need to set always-use-default-target="true" in `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` in my spring boot application. How can i do that? I tried:

```
@Bean
SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler handler() {
    SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler handler = new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    handler.setAlwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl(true);
    return  handler;
}
```

but no success. seems like completely different bean is being used

my security config:

```
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@Configuration
@Order(2)
public class FormWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails oAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login**", "/assets/**", "/uaa/**", "/management/health").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .headers()
                .defaultsDisabled()
                .frameOptions()
                .sameOrigin()
            .and()
                .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                .ignoringAntMatchers("/uaa/**")
            .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .permitAll();
    }
}
```

and:

```
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public class ApiWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails oAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .antMatcher("/api/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                .successForwardUrl("/")
            .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new Unauthorized401EntryPoint());
    }

    public static class Unauthorized401EntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

        @Override
        public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception)
                throws IOException, ServletException {

            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried as declaring new bean, i tried setting `.successHandler(...)` i tried `defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)` none worked

Comment: Setting `.successHandler(...)` should work. Could you [edit] your question with the code setting the success handler? Do we talk about form authentication?

Comment: this uses oauth so it redirects do identity provider and then redirect back to /login

Comment: Could you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47693963/spring-oauth-2-facebook-authentication-redirects-user-to-my-home-page? Maybe it helps you.

Answer (score 4):

Use following for annotation based settings:

```
defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard",true)
```

The second boolean parameter is setting `always-use-default-target` to `true`.