# Spring Oauth 2 Facebook Authentication Redirects User To My Home Page

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-social-facebook

I am trying to redirect a user who have been authenticated to another page other than the home page. I am using spring boot 1.5.6 and Oauth 2. User is authenticated but was redirected to the home page. I don't understand why this is happening. Please, someone should help me. Some answers to related problem on stackoverflow and the internet didn't help me.

Here is my SecurityConfig file

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalAuthentication
@EnableOAuth2Client
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Order(2)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

@Autowired
private OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext;

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
private GeneralConfig generalConfig;

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    super.configure(web);
}

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

   http.authorizeRequests()
   .antMatchers("/user*")
   .access("hasRole('CUSTOMER')")
   .and()

   .formLogin()
   .loginPage("/loginUser")
   .loginProcessingUrl("/user_login")
   .failureUrl("/loginUser?error=loginError")
   .defaultSuccessUrl("/customer/dashboard")

   .and()
   .logout()
   .logoutUrl("/user_logout")
   .logoutSuccessUrl("/loginUser").permitAll()
   .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")

   .and()
   .exceptionHandling()
   .accessDeniedPage("/403")

   .and()
   .csrf().disable()
   .addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);  

}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws               Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).
    passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws 
Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
}

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBeanoauth2ClientFilterRegistration
(OAuth2ClientContextFilter filter) {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registration.setFilter(filter);
    registration.setOrder(-100);
    return registration;
}

private Filter ssoFilter(ClientResources client, String path) {
    OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter = new      
    OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(path);
    OAuth2RestTemplate template = new  
    OAuth2RestTemplate(client.getClient(), oauth2ClientContext);
    filter.setRestTemplate(template);
    UserInfoTokenServices tokenServices = new  
         UserInfoTokenServices(client.getResource().getUserInfoUri(),
         client.getClient().getClientId());
    tokenServices.setRestTemplate(template);
    filter.setTokenServices(tokenServices);
    return filter;
}

private Filter ssoFilter() {
    CompositeFilter filter = new CompositeFilter();
    List<Filter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
    filters.add(ssoFilter(facebook(), "/signin/facebook"));
    filters.add(ssoFilter(google(), "/signin/google"));
    filter.setFilters(filters);
    return filter;
}

@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("google")
public ClientResources google() {
    return new ClientResources();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("facebook")
public ClientResources facebook() {
    return new ClientResources();
}
```

}

From the SecurityConfig I expect the user upon successful authentication to be redirected to customer/dashboard so that I can do further processing. I know the user is authenticated because I can access their data. It's not just redirecting to the right page

But instead it keep redirecting the user to the home page. What am I doing wrong? I also have another Security Config File for admin. I can provide it if required.

Comment: So I have this http://localhost:8080/signin/facebook configured as my redirect url in facebook console. When you say in the client, are you talking about the controller or SecurityConfig file. What exactly is the client you are talking about? And please, show me an example.

Comment: I have a link '/signin/facebook' on my form that redirects to facebook. In SecurityConfig, I have .defaultSuccessUrl("/central/dashboard") where facebook is suppose to redirect to upon successful authentication. I never called '/' anywhere in my configuration

Comment: Thanks a million. It worked like charm. I don't know how to express my gratitude to you. Thank u very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the default strategy, you have to set an [`AuthenticationSuccessHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.1.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationSuccessHandler.html), see [`AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter#setAuthenticationSuccessHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.1.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.html#setAuthenticationSuccessHandler-org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler-):

> Sets the strategy used to handle a successful authentication. By default a `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` is used.

Your modified code:

```java
private Filter ssoFilter(ClientResources client, String path) {
    OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(path);
    OAuth2RestTemplate template = new OAuth2RestTemplate(client.getClient(), oauth2ClientContext);
    filter.setRestTemplate(template);
    UserInfoTokenServices tokenServices = new UserInfoTokenServices(client.getResource().getUserInfoUri(),client.getClient().getClientId());
    tokenServices.setRestTemplate(template);
    filter.setTokenServices(tokenServices);
    filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler("/customer/dashboard")‌​;
    return filter;
}
```