# How to redirect to the last requested page, but SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler redirects to the last PROTECTED one?

Tags: authentication, spring-security

I want users to redirect to the last page they requested after authentification, but in the case of several requests (protected and than unprotected) it does not work. How can I fix it?

I overrided onAuthenticationSuccess method of the SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler and it works fine, but I have one case - when the user tries to open protected url, he gots login form, but does not login for a moment and instead opens not protected (usual) link. after that he clicks login button, passes the authentification, and he is redirected back to the very first protected url (but I want him to be redirected to the last one, unprotected.

I do something like this to do it:

```java
public class myHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication
    ) throws IOException, ServletException {
        setUseReferer(
            !request.getHeader("referer").contains("/login")
        );
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }
}
```

for example:

user tries /administration

gets /login

clicks /about_us link

clicks "login" button and goes to /login

is redirected to /administration (but I want him to be back at /about_us)

How can I do it?

Comment: The question and the steps you have written is bit confusing but you can visit below links may be you can find something there. 

https://www.baeldung.com/spring_redirect_after_login    AND
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47558375/how-to-set-always-use-default-target-in-spring-security (see the last answer)

Comment: Sorry, it does not solve the problem:(